# How to reuse a Style with ContentControl to make code more compact?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, refactoring, reusability

I have the following (working) code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Menu>
        <Menu.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="MenuItemStyle">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightSlateGray" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="DeleteMenuStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Icon">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource CrossIconScalable}"
                                Width="15"
                                Height="15"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="SaveMenuStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Icon">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource SaveButtonScalable}"
                                Width="15"
                                Height="15"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Menu.Resources>
        <MenuItem>
            <MenuItem.Header>
               <!-- ... -->
            </MenuItem.Header>
            <MenuItem Name="SaveImageMenu" Header="{Binding MenuItemSaveTxt}"
                      Click="SaveImageMenu_OnClick" Style="{StaticResource SaveMenuStyle}" />
            <MenuItem Name="DeleteViewMenu" Header="{Binding MenuItemCancTxt}"
                      Click="DeleteViewMenu_OnClick" Style="{StaticResource DeleteMenuStyle}" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</StackPanel>

<!-- StaticResources definition -->
<Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="SaveButtonScalable">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
                    <Canvas Name="Capa_1" Width="32" Height="32">
                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <Canvas.Resources />
                        <Canvas Name="g3">
                            <Path Name="path5" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <PathGeometry Figures="M26 0h-2v13H8V0H0v32h32V6L26 0z M28 30H4V16h24V30z"
                                                  FillRule="NonZero" />
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
                            <Rectangle Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="18" Width="20" Height="2" Name="rect7"
                                       Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                            <Rectangle Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="22" Width="20" Height="2" Name="rect9"
                                       Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                            <Rectangle Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="26" Width="20" Height="2" Name="rect11"
                                       Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                            <Rectangle Canvas.Left="18" Canvas.Top="2" Width="4" Height="9" Name="rect13"
                                       Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </Canvas>
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="CrossIconScalable">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
                    <Canvas Name="svg2" Width="32" Height="32">
                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <Canvas.Resources/>
                        <Path Name="path4">
                            <Path.Data>
                                <PathGeometry Figures="m0 0h32v32h-32z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                            </Path.Data>
                        </Path>
                        <Path Name="path6" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                            <Path.Data>
                                <PathGeometry Figures="m2 26 4 4 10-10 10 10 4-4-10-10 10-10-4-4-10 10-10-10-4 4 10 10z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                            </Path.Data>
                        </Path>
                    </Canvas>
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As you can see there is some repetition of code here:

- The two declared `Style` elements (`DeleteMenuStyle` and `SaveMenuStyle`) are identical except for the `<Style>` used for each `ContenControl`.
- The `SaveButtonScalable` and `CrossIconScalable` Styles are identical for the parent tag but they differs in the `<Canvas>` tag inside.

I'd like to refactor this in order to create code which is more compact and without any repetition.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where is the huge repetition of code? Can you explain?

Comment: In the two styles, everything but the static resource is repeated. I'd like to merge the two declaration in one

Comment: What's in the `CrossIconScalable` and `SaveButtonScalable` styles? Given you're using `ControlControl`, can you declare `DataTemplate` for each type of menu item instead, binding an appropriate view model object as the context? Without a good [mcve] it's difficult to understand what your options here are, i.e. how to accommodate whatever the rest of your code looks like, and what options you might have for cleaning things up.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sorry for the lack of information, now I added some more detail to my question :)

Comment: Sorry, that's still not a good [mcve]. It's more detail, but still incomplete. It's important what's in the `Canvas`, because really the best way to do this is to declare a `DataTemplate` for the content, and then just set the `MenuItem.DataContext` to the content, rather than messing with the `Style`. Based on the "SVG" in your code, I suspect you have a `PathGeometry` or similar, which can be the data type for a template that then applies that geometry to a drawing in the template. I could post an example as an answer, but without specifics, I can't be sure it would help.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Added also the canvas code (I avoided it because it seems to me too verbose, but, clearly, it was wrong). Now I try to refactor this using DataTemplate and MenuItem.DataContext. If you post an example it would be great to start learning WPF in the right way for me ;) I'll accept (and offer you a beer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, that was close enough to a good MCVE that I think I can provide some useful information. :)

In your particular case, it seems you want to be able to propagate the `Foreground` value down into the template, so `DataTemplate` isn't going to work, at least not without creating a new helper data structure to do that work. So, sticking with the `ControlTemplate` idea, you can consolidate the XAML you posted with something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO36775094RefactorStyle.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <!--
      Adding the 'p' namespace qualifier above allows Style elements to be
      formatted correctly on Stack Overflow
  -->
  <Window.Resources>
    <StreamGeometry x:Key="saveButtonGeometry">
      F1 M26,0 h-2 v13 H8 V0 H0 v32 h32 V6 L26,0 z M28,30 H4 V16 h24 V30 z
      M6,18 h20 v2 h-20 z m0,4 h20 v2 h-20 z m0,4 h20 v2 h-20 z M18,2 h4 v9 h-4 z
    </StreamGeometry>

    <StreamGeometry x:Key="crossButtonGeometry">
      F1 m2 26 4 4 10-10 10 10 4-4-10-10 10-10-4-4-10 10-10-10-4 4 10 10z
    </StreamGeometry>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="geometryContentTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
      <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Canvas Name="Capa_1" Width="32" Height="32">
          <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <!--
                Not sure why you set this here, since translating 0,0
                does nothing, but I've left it in :)
            -->
            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
          </Canvas.RenderTransform>
          <Canvas.Resources />
          <Canvas Name="g3">
            <Path Name="path5" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="{Binding}"/>
          </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
      </Viewbox>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <Menu>
      <Menu.Resources>
        <p:Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="MenuItemStyle">
          <p:Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightSlateGray" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
          </p:Style.Triggers>
        </p:Style>

        <!--
            These styles do nothing other than set the Icon property, so if you
            wanted to, you could just set each of these ContentControl instances
            on the MenuItem.Icon value directly, and then just use MenuItemStyle
            as the actual style for each MenuItem.
        -->
        <p:Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="DeleteMenuStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}">
          <Setter Property="Icon">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource geometryContentTemplate}"
                              DataContext="{StaticResource crossButtonGeometry}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </p:Style>
        <p:Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="SaveMenuStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}">
          <Setter Property="Icon">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource geometryContentTemplate}"
                              DataContext="{StaticResource saveButtonGeometry}"
                              Width="15" Height="15"/>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </p:Style>
      </Menu.Resources>
      <MenuItem Header="Menu">
        <MenuItem Name="SaveImageMenu" Header="{Binding MenuItemSaveTxt}"
                  Click="SaveImageMenu_OnClick" Style="{StaticResource SaveMenuStyle}" />
        <MenuItem Name="DeleteViewMenu" Header="{Binding MenuItemCancTxt}"
                  Click="DeleteViewMenu_OnClick" Style="{StaticResource DeleteMenuStyle}" />
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The idea being that you define the `ControlTemplate` only once, and then reference the part that's different — i.e. the geometry — when you actually declare a `ContentControl` using the template.

I'll note that in your example, your `CrossIconScalable` style included a `path4` element that appeared to be unused. It did not specify any fill, and so while you had a geometry there, it didn't have any effect on the visual appearance. So I just left it out. But doing so does "cheat" a little; you could not use *exactly* the above approach if you really did have two different parts in your template that needed to be filled differently, because there's no direct way to declare two different `DataContext` values (i.e. two different geometries, one for each fill value you want to use).

In your example, where you want to be able to use `{TemplateBinding}` to refer to the parent's property value, you would need to work around this by making a helper class to represent the geometries, e.g. something like:

```
class TemplateGeometry
{
    public Geometry ForegroundGeometry { get; set; }
    public Geometry BackgroundGeometry { get; set; }
}
```

Then you'd declare your resource something like this:

```
<l:TemplateGeometry x:Key="templateGeometry1">
  <l:TemplateGeometry.ForegroundGeometry>
    <StreamGeometry>
      <!-- your foreground geometry here -->
    </StreamGeometry>
  </l:TemplateGeometry.ForegroundGeometry>
  <l:TemplateGeometry.BackgroundGeometry>
    <StreamGeometry>
      <!-- your background geometry here -->
    </StreamGeometry>
  </l:TemplateGeometry.BackgroundGeometry>
</l:TemplateGeometry>
```

The template could look (in part) like this:

```
          <Canvas>
            <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Data="{Binding BackgroundGeometry}"/>
            <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="{Binding ForegroundGeometry}"/>
          </Canvas>
```

And then of course you'd set the `DataContext` to the helper class instance instead of a geometry directly:

```
              <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource geometryContentTemplate}"
                              DataContext="{StaticResource templateGeometry1}"
                              Width="15" Height="15"/>
```

The above is just the basic technique. As you can probably see, there are lots of variations you could apply to accomplish exactly what you want.

Finally, I'll just mention that the `DataTemplate` approach is very similar. The main issue is that all a `DataTemplate` has access to is the binding context object's members and not `{TemplateBinding}` members. One of the very nice things about `DataTemplate` is that you can set it up, through the use of the `DataType` property of the template, such that you don't even need to reference the template explicitly. A `ContentControl` will automatically find the correct template and apply it, according to the type of the context object used.